# rsync : dont delete few files in source after upload

Tags: linux, shell, networking, server, rsync

I want to write a shell script to use **rsync** to transfer files between folders called `source` and `destination`.

Contents of **source** folder

```
A
B
C
test1.log
test2.json
```

I would like to transfer all files from **source** to **destination**, and want to delete all source files except `test1.log` and `test2.json`

i.e after uploading all files to destination, 
Content of **source** folder should be :

```
test1.log
test2.json
```

Contents of destination folder should be :

```
    A
    B
    C
test1.log
test2.json
```

I experimented with

```
rsync -aP --timeout=120 --remove-source-files -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /id" source user@1.1.1.1:/destination_path/ --exclude=test1.log --exclude=test2.json
```

But in that case, `test1.log` and `test2.json` are excluded from uploading itself.

But I want all files to be uploaded to destination, most of them deleted from source after upload, but want to keep few files in source.

Is there any way to do it with `rsync`?

Comment: `rsync` never deletes something from the source directory (see the man page of delete). If you want to delete it from the source, use a `rm` command afterwards.

Comment: From rsync man page : --remove-source-files  - sender removes synchronized files (non-dir). If --remove-source-files is used, once the sender send the file, those are deleted from the source folder. No need to use `rm` command I think.

Comment: Oops, I overlooked this part. Thank you for pointing this out. However, from my understanding of the rsync man-page, this would erase all files which have been transfered. You can not choose to remove only some of them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `user1934428` pointed out,if I use `--remove-source-files` there is no way to keep some files not deleted after transfer. 
So I ended up in using the below solution, which is not efficient since `rsync` has to be called twice.

```
rsync -aP --timeout=120 --remove-source-files -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /id" source user@1.1.1.1:/destination_path/ --exclude=test1.log --exclude=test2.json

rsync -aP --timeout=120 -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /id" source user@1.1.1.1:/destination_path/
```